# Getting KeyError = 0 error ,while i am using np.nanprod on two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

```
cond1 = df['MODEL'].isin(["MC"]) & df['MC_LGD_ULSTER_FLAG'].isin(["N"])
cond2 = df['MODEL'].isin(["MC"]) & df['MC_LGD_ULSTER_FLAG'].isin(["Y"])

for j in range(1,12):
    if j == 11:
        df.loc[cond1,'TOTAL_CALIBRATED_SCORE_IFRS9_'+str(j)] = np.nansum((np.nanprod((df.loc[cond1,'MID_CORPORATE_LGD_SCORE'],df.loc[cond1,'MC_COEFF_UK']),axis=0),\
                                                                df.loc[cond1,'MC_INT_UK'] ,\
                                                                np.nanprod((df.loc[cond1,'ZGAP_COEFF_UK'],df.loc[cond1,'ZGAP_S0']),axis=0)),axis=0).round(decimals=6)
        **df.loc[cond2,'TOTAL_CALIBRATED_SCORE_IFRS9_'+str(j)] = np.nansum((np.nanprod((df.loc[cond2,'MID_CORPORATE_LGD_SCORE'],df.loc[cond2,'MC_COEFF_ROI']),axis=0), \
                                                                df.loc[cond2,'MC_INT_ROI'] , \
                                                                np.nanprod((df.loc[cond2,'ZGAP_COEFF_ROI'],df.loc[cond2,'ZGAP_S0']),axis=0)),axis=0).round(decimals=6)**
```

cond1 is running without error but cond2 running with KeyError :2 , i checked all required columns which i am using for calculation, there is no whitespace and mention "skipinitialspace=True" while creating dataframe.

Comment: Note that `.isin(['some_element'])` is eqivalent to `.eq('some_element')`.

Comment: didn't get you ? Could you please elaborate it little bit .

Comment: checked with .eq('some_element') but still getting same issue. 
cond1 = df['MODEL'].eq("MC") & df['MC_LGD_ULSTER_FLAG'].eq("N")
cond2 = df['MODEL'].eq("MC") & df['MC_LGD_ULSTER_FLAG'].eq("Y")